# Grails 2.3.8 console reset all possible?

Tags: grails

I am using the Grails console to do some GORM experimentation for educational purposes and after executing some commands I wish I could quickly delete all objects I just created and start a fresh session. Is there any quick shortcut way to do this or "reset" the console rather than having to exit the console and restart it each time?